# how to perform a sequential pivot in an MS ACCESS database in dapper with VB.NET

Tags: sql, linq, ms-access, pivot

I'm trying to perform a sequential pivot in an MS ACCESS database in dapper with VB.NET

I have the code below, but this is still wrong.

is there any other method please guide me

Thanks

```vb
Public Class Form2
    Dim tps As New Tableproductservice()

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = tps.Loaddata("A")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Tableproductservice
    Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\transposerowtocolumnsqlmsaccessvbnet.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"

    Public Function Loaddata(CodeProduct As String) As IEnumerable(Of Tableproduct)
        Dim sql = <sql>
                              TRANSFORM Sum(Tableproduct.[Qty]) AS SumOfQty
        SELECT Tableproduct.Codeproduct AS [CodeProduct], Tableproduct.Colour AS [Colour], Sum(Tableproduct.Qty) AS [Total]
        FROM Tableproduct INNER JOIN SizeProduct ON Tableproduct.Size = SizeProduct.Size
        WHERE Tableproduct.Codeproduct = 'A'
        GROUP BY Tableproduct.Codeproduct, Tableproduct.Colour
        PIVOT SizeProduct.Size;
                          </sql>.Value
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Return _conn.Query(Of Tableproduct)(sql, New With {Key .CodeProduct = CodeProduct}).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Tableproduct
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Colour() As String
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
    Public Property Total() As Integer
End Class

Public Class SizeProduct
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Sequence() As Integer
End Class
```

But the result in datagridview does not pivot is there anything wrong please guide me
below screenshot of results in datagridview

[image: Screenshot_datagridviewQueryCodeProductA]

but with the same sql in vb.net results in MS ACCESS database have been pivoted but not yet sequentially.
below screenshot of results in MS-ACCESS database

[image: Screenshot_QueryCodeProductA]

[image: Screenshot_QueryCodeProductB]

Sample Data :

Table `TableProduct`

| CodeProduct | Colour | Size | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | White | S | 15 |
| A | Black | M | 20 |
| A | White | L | 10 |
| B | Blue | S | 20 |
| B | White | XL | 15 |

Table `Sizeproduct`

| Sizeproduct | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| S | 1 |
| M | 2 |
| L | 3 |
| XL | 4 |

Desired Result :

Where For Codeproduct : A

| CodeProduct | Colour | S | M | L | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Black |  | 20 |  | 20 |
| A | White | 15 |  | 10 | 25 |

Where For Codeproduct : B

| CodeProduct | Colour | S | XL | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | Blue | 20 |  | 20 |
| B | White |  | 15 | 15 |

Result in datagridview answer from @OlivierJacot-Descombes

[image: answerdatagridviewQueryCodeProductA]

[image: answerdatagridviewQueryCodeProductB]

Comment: Well, your `Loaddata` method awlays returns `Tableproduct` objects and this is the only thing your datagridview sees. You must create a class which represents your pivoted result and return it from the `Loaddata` method.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes , `You must create a class which represents your pivoted result and return it from the Loaddata method.` thank you your reply please guide me and whether it can be applied in appropriate sequentially based on `Sizeproduct`

Comment: VB.Net has multiline string literals. You don't need to use xml literals anymore.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , 
Thank you for the information

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77356393/861716) and repost questions. It's conduct that may lead to a question ban. You should have edited the deleted question, which also preserves efforts others have put into commenting and offering suggestions for improvement.

Comment: @GertArnold , 
Thank you for your suggestion but before the previous post it was closed automatically so I couldn't edit it

Comment: If it's closed you can still edit it, that's in fact what you're supposed to do: edit and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `Loaddata` method always returns `Tableproduct` objects and this is the only thing your DataGridView sees. You must create a class which represents your pivoted result and return it from the `Loaddata` method.

```vb
Public Class PivotedProduct
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Colour() As String

    Public Property S() As Integer
    Public Property M() As Integer
    Public Property L() As Integer
    Public Property XL() As Integer

    Public Property Total() As Integer
End Class
```

But this will of course always display all the size columns in the grid. I am not sure what you mean by "sequential". If you mean grouped by product, then this cannot be achieved with the `DataGridView`. But some third-party grids are available that support grouping.

If you want to display only the relevant size columns per grouped product, then this will be difficult or impossible with a grid control. But it would be possible to solve this problem with a reporting tool and some logic.

Here is an example loading the data in the grid and hiding empty columns (but only for one product at a time). I created a service loading some fake test data for testing:

```vb
Public Class PivotedProductService
    Public Function LoadData(CodeProduct As String) As IEnumerable(Of PivotedProduct)
        Return New List(Of PivotedProduct) From {
            New PivotedProduct With {.CodeProduct = "B", .Colour = "Blue", .S = 20, .Total = 20},
            New PivotedProduct With {.CodeProduct = "B", .Colour = "White", .XL = 15, .Total = 15}
        }
    End Function
End Class
```

My form code looks like this:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim pps As New PivotedProductService

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = pps.LoadData("B")
        HideEmptySizeColumns()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HideEmptySizeColumns()
        For i As Integer = 2 To 5
            Dim allZeros = True
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                If row.Cells(i).Value <> 0 Then
                    allZeros = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If allZeros Then
                DataGridView1.Columns(i).Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

---

Using LINQ you can simplify the code for hiding the columns like this

```vb
Private Sub HideEmptySizeColumns()
    For i As Integer = 2 To 5
        Dim allZeros = Not (From row In DataGridView1.Rows
                            Where row.Cells(i).Value <> 0).Any()
        If allZeros Then
            DataGridView1.Columns(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . Only I want the datagridview column to appear according to the size available for the codeproduct. I've updated in the post screenshots of the results of your answer so that I marked the blue color it didn't show up how to solve it didn't show up. Please guide me. `I am not sure what you mean by "sequential".` From your answers it is already arranged in sequential in size

Comment: ,Your answer went perfectly. Thank you

Comment: hello sir. I have warning `Warning BC42327 Using the iteration variable in a query expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable` for this line code `Where row.Cells(i).Value <> 0).Any()` for variable `i`

Comment: Yes, you can copy `i` to a local variable in the loop to get rid of this warning. `Dim index = i` and then use `Cells(index)`. But since the LINQ query is evaluated at each iteration with `Any()`, the problem the warning describes does not occur here.

Comment: thanks for the response sorry I am late Reply