# how to solve Auto-implemented properties cannot have parameters & Identifier expected in Property class/model in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, model, properties

I'm trying to solve Auto-implemented properties cannot have parameters & Identifier expected in class/model in vb.net.

because the database has field names like that so I have to set the name property in the class or model
Please Guide me.

Thanks

```
 Public Class PivotSizeStocksin
        Public Property -() As Integer    'Identifier expected
        Public Property XS/SS() As Integer  'Auto-implemented properties cannot have parameters
        Public Property XXL/2L() As Integer 'Identifier expected
        Public Property XXXL/3L() As Integer 'Identifier expected
        Public Property XXXXL/4L() As Integer 'Identifier expected
    End Class
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902674/14171304 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/48407241/14171304. If you also need a grid's headers to display the real db names, decorate each property with the `<DisplayName("DB-Column-Name")>` attribute. Alternative, use valid model property names as aliases in the `SELECT` sql to select. i.e. `SELECT - AS Dash, XS/SS AS XSSS FROM ...`.

Comment: @dr.null , 
Actually, this is the pivot result that I want to use for the RDLC report according to this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77359410/how-to-perform-a-sequential-pivot-in-an-ms-access-database-in-dapper-with-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment136391801_77359410) . 
so the real property is `Public Property Size() As String` 
is there any other solution?

Comment: Now, edit your question and make it self-contained. What do you get from the referred answer? What is the business of this creepy model? What is the desired output? Where is the db query? What is the Pivot mode? If you are just asking here if there's any way to have property names as such. The answer is No.

Comment: @dr.null , 
actually this is only for printpreview and print purposes. actually this is only for the purpose of printpreview and print and so I have a solution without using the name property so just use the datatable and then convert to html to print the contents of the datatable. So I will make a new post, I hope you can help me

Comment: @dr.null , I have posted the latest maybe you can help me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77371933/how-to-print-contents-of-datatable-in-html-in-printpreview-and-direct-print-incl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the parentheses. They are used to specify parameters for properties. As the error message says, auto-implemented properties (those without explicit getter and setter) cannot have parameters.

There are rules about what characters can be used in identifiers, i.e. names of types, members, etc. How could you use slashes and dashes in an identifier when it would then be impossible to differentiate between them and mathematical operators? You can only use letters, digits and underscores in an identifier and the first character cannot be a digit.